# How to see $\ell_0$-penalty is non-convex function?

Tags: probability, statistics, convex-analysis

$$\hat{\beta}(\lambda) = \arg \min_\beta   (|| Y - X\beta ||_2^2 /n + \lambda ||\beta||_0)$$

where the $\ell_0$-penalty is $|| \beta||_0 = \Sigma_{j=1}^p 1(\beta_j \neq 0)$.

The textbook says "the estimator above is infeasible to compute when p is of medium or large size since the $\ell_0$-penalty is a non-convex function in $\beta$".

I don't know how to see $\ell_0$-penalty is a non-convex function in $\beta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $f$ to be convex, you need
$$
f(\frac{\beta_1+\beta_2}{2})\le \frac 1{2}f(\beta_1)+\frac 1{2}f(\beta_2).
$$
Choosing $\beta_1=(1,0)$ and $\beta_2=(0,1)$ you have $f(\beta_1)=1$, $f(\beta_2)=1$, while $\frac{\beta_1+\beta_2}{2}=(1/2,1/2)$ and so $f(\frac{\beta_1+\beta_2}{2})=f((1/2,1/2))=2$.

On the other hand,
$$
\frac{1}{2}f(\beta_1)+\frac 1{2}f(\beta_2)=1/2+1/2=1,
$$
so the convexity inequality does not hold and $f(\cdot)=\|\cdot\|_0$ is not convex.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ are two vectors $\beta$ such that $\|\beta\|_0 \leq 1$. However, the convex combination of the two $\frac12 (1, 0) + \frac12 (0, 1) = (1/2, 1/2)$ does not satisfy $\|\beta\|_0 \leq 1$. For a convex function $f$, $\{\beta : f(\beta)\leq 1\}$ should be a convex set.

Comment: Can you explain "For a convex function $f$, $\{\beta : f(\beta)\leq 1\}$ should be a convex set."?

Comment: @Jackie See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function).  Here $f(\beta)=1$ at the end points and $2$ in between, so does not meet the definition