# How to see Lasso penalty is convex?

Tags: probability, statistics, convex-optimization

$$\hat{\beta}(\lambda) = \arg \min_\beta   (|| Y - X\beta ||_2^2 /n + \lambda ||\beta||_1)$$

It says the whole optimization above is convex. I know the logic here. Both the sum of squares and the lasso penalty are
convex, and so is the lasso loss function. But I don't know how to see "the lasso penalty are
convex".

Comment: It helps to know that any norm is convex, including the $\ell_1$-norm.

Comment: @littleO thank you! but L_0 norm is non-convex.

Comment: The $\ell_0$-penalty isn’t a true norm, though. To be precise it shouldn’t be called a norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lasso penalty is, up to a positive scalar factor $\lambda$, the function
$$
\beta\to \|\beta\|_{l^1}=\sum_i|\beta_i|
$$
This function is convex, being a sum of convex functions $\beta\to|\beta_i|$.
More generally, any norm is convex:
$$
\|\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y\|\le \|\alpha x\|+\|(1-\alpha)y\|=\alpha\|x\|+(1-\alpha)\|y\|
$$
by the triangle inequality and the (positive) homogeneity of the norm.

Comment: but L0 norm is non-convex.

Comment: It is not a norm, really. All norms are convex as my proof shows. They may call it $l_0$ norm but it is not a norm.

Comment: Thanks. In the step of triangle inequality, is this true for any vector (real numbers)? i.e., do we need to care about the positivity?

Comment: No, you don't. The property is completely general.

Comment: I like your answer, which I can understand easily. Could you help me a related question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4767986/how-to-see-ell-0-penalty-is-non-convex-function/4768073?noredirect=1#comment10127534_4768073

Comment: @Jackie That question seems to be very similar. What is that you do not understand?

Comment: I want an answer that uses the basic definition of convex function, as you did here. I don't understand "For a convex function $f$, $\{\beta : f(\beta)\leq 1\}$ should be a convex set."

Comment: For $f$ to be convex, you need $f(\frac{\beta_1+\beta_2}{2})\le \frac 1{2}f(\beta_1)+\frac 1{2}f(\beta_2)$. Choosing $\beta_1=(1,0)$ and $\beta_2=(0,1)$ you have $f(\beta_1)=1$, $f(\beta_2)=1$, while $\frac{\beta_1+\beta_2}{2}=(1/2,1/2)$ and so $f(\frac{\beta_1+\beta_2}{2})=f((1/2,1/2))=2$. On the other hand, $\frac{1}{2}f(\beta_1)+\frac 1{2}f(\beta_2)$=1/2+1/2=1$, so the convexity inequality does not hold.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you mind answering the question on that website? So I can pick your answer and allow other readers to see.

Comment: OK, I can certainly do that.